# Whom vs Who: object Judas + whom

Tags: objects, whom

> The test itself lies in attempting to apply this new update to a card belonging to Judas, **whom is** a legitimate user of the system.

Is *Judas* considered the subject or the object? I'm considering *Judas* to be the object and hence applying *whom* after the comma. Is this correct?

I read about *whom* vs *who* at [LINK](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/who-versus-whom?page=1), but I'm not sure if I'm applying it correctly to this case. I've also tried the *whom+him* test by asking *Whom does the card belong to?* with the answer *It belongs to him*.

Comment: This is a mistake. It should be 'who'.

Comment: You may be interested in [this](http://theoatmeal.com/comics/who_vs_whom).

Comment: *Whom* can never be the subject, and therefore it is of course incorrect ever to write “whom is”, unless you are writing *“Whom* is never allowed to stand as the subject of a verb.” :) Well, or ***“Whom is** your mother planning on inviting?”*

Comment: Good thing I asked, had it all wrong. @BrianHooper That link is great!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name *Judas* is indeed the object of the phrase in which it appears.  However, this has no bearing on the selection of pronoun in a subsequent phrase, where the name can be used in a different function.

If you apply the "whom/him" test to the phrase where you're actually trying to use who/whom, you'll get

> Who is a legitimate user of the system?  He is a legitimate user of the system.

as opposed to the clearly incorrect version:

> Whom is a legitimate user of the system?  Him is a legitimate user of the system.

Comment: Correct - the function of Judas in the participle is the subject *of that clause*

Comment: The he/him test is so easy and obvious that I wonder why it is not pointed out more often.

Comment: Basically, because native Anglophones are not taught about their language in school. They are taught composition and literature in English classes, but not grammar. What is called "grammar" in Anglophone schools is mostly misinformation, handed down by the teachers' teachers, unto the Nth generation. This is true of math, too; but many people study math beyond the third-grade level. Very few people study grammar.

Answer (score -1):

The [Oatmeal](http://theoatmeal.com) guy explains that using cartoons: [How and why to use whom in a sentence](http://theoatmeal.com/comics/who_vs_whom).