# Why was "whom he thought would be" marked as incorrect if "whom he saw improve" is correct?

Tags: whom

I answered two questions incorrectly during my SAT prep class, and they seem to contradict each other. The first question was:

> The district manager agreed to promote the employee ***who he saw improve*** sales by the end of the year.
>
> (A) who he saw improve
>
> (B) who he saw was improving
>
> (C) who he will see improve
>
> (D) whom he saw improve
>
> (E) whom he saw to be improving

I picked A but the correct answer was D. Now, for my second question:

> During the auditions, the show's producer looked for those actors ***whom he thought*** would be suitable for the many roles in the play.
>
> (A) whom he thought
>
> (B) whom he has thought
>
> (C) who he was thinking
>
> (D) who he thought
>
> (E) whom they thought

Again, I picked A here but the the correct answer was D. I don't understand why one uses "who" while the other uses "whom", since they seem to have the same sentence structure (but obviously different words).

Comment: See also [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/123764/43980) and the comments and links there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are not the same structure at all.

The first is equivalent to

> The strict manager saw **him** (that is, the employee) improve sales.

If you see him do something, then you still see him.

While the second is equivalent to:

> The show’s producer thought *he* (that is, the actor) would be suitable.

If he would be suitable, it is just he, no matter the thinking.

Since those are the correct *he/him* answers, just plug *who/whom* in correspondingly.

Comment: Per the linked question (see duplicate question indicator), this logic is incorrect.  Both uses should be `whom`, as neither represents the subject **of that clause**.  In both your reductions, `he` and `him` represent direct objects, not subjects.  You could argue that `he would be suitable` forms its own clause with an implied `that` in which `he` becomes the subject, but that is a result if your transformation and is not present in the original sentence.

Comment: @Zenexer No, *he* does **not** represent a direct object in my reduction; the direct object of *thought* is the entire subordinate clause *he would be suitable*. If *he* were a direct object, *he* would be *him* and it is not. Are you claiming that the test-supplied would-be correct answer to the second problem in the OP is actually wrong?

Comment: Right, in your reduction, `he` is the subject (of a clause) because you created an additional prepositional phrase with an implied `that`.  Without reduction--just splitting up the original sentence into phrases and clauses--it's easy to see that it's an object in question.

Comment: @Zenexer What prepositional phrase??

Comment: "The show's producer thought **[that] he would be suitable**."  Colloquially we often drop "that" as a preposition.  Regardless, "he would be suitable" is a new clause.

Comment: Sorry, it's not considered a prepositional phrase; it's just a clause.  My mistake.

Comment: Simple breakdown: `During the auditions, {the show's producer(S) looked for those actors(IO)} {whom(DO) he(S) thought} {(S:actors/whom) would be suitable for the many roles(IO) in the play(IO)}.`  As you can see, `whom` is an object.

Comment: @Zenexer Well you may believe, but it doesn’t look that way from here.

Comment: In the last clause, `actors` becomes an implied subject.  Your sentence deals with the last clause, where `would` is the verb.  If `who/m` were there, you'd be right.  It should be: `He [the producer] thought they [the actors] would be suitable.`  Alternatively, `He thought them/him suitable.`